# How to fix alignment on flex box with images and text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox, that has a few products in it, the products are comprised of an image and some text. The problem is that any of the products that have more than one line of text has an issue where the image is slightly raised above the others.

Any idea on how to fix this?

My code is below

```
    <div class='imggrid'>
        <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>Product Title</h3>
        </div>
            <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>Product Title with More Words</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>The Joiners Tee</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>The Joiners Tee</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>The Joiners Tee</h3>
        </div>
        <div class='product'>
            <img src="assets/images/merch/01.png" alt="The Joiners Tee">
            <h3>The Joiners Tee</h3>
        </div>

    </div>
```

css

```
.imggrid {
  width: 80vw;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.imggrid img {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Did you definitely want to display the products in columns, rather than rows?

Comment: Ah apologies, they are in columns on mobile but rows in a media query later on. They are positioned correctly it's just that when the text below has more than one line the images are pushed up slightly

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the following line in your css:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will help clear some default padding